# StreamInsight Query - Hopping Window Help

Tags: streaminsight

I want to send a window of payloads to my output adapter. I need all of them to go to my output adapter at the same time, and not one by one.

So, so far I have:

`var filteredCepStream = (from window in cepStream.HoppingWindow(
                    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(outputConfig.WindowLength),
                    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(outputConfig.WindowHopSize),
                    HoppingWindowOutputPolicy.ClipToWindowEnd)
                    select window);`

But StreamInsight won’t let me send over a window. Is there any way to make a user defined aggregate or something to convert this to a list of payloads to send to the output adapter? Am I going about this is wrong way? I really need ALL of the payloads in my window to be sent to the output adapter at the same time.

Thank you!!

Dina

Answer (score 0):

Answered on MSDN: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/streaminsight/thread/9a986967-93a2-4715-abcb-12c40b9dddb1